# Complexity (calculating big O)

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

I've been working through some problems in my textbook that are about calculating the big O complexity of algorithms. One of the questions i'm stumped on doesn't have an answer in the back and i'd appreciate any input.

You have an array of length n-1 containing linked lists that contain lists of words. Each linked list is first insertion sorted and then using the first word in the linked list, the array is quicksorted. What is the big O complexity of this algorithm?

I already know that:

Traversing a linked list is O(n)
insertion sort is O(n^2)
Quick Sort is (nlogn)

I'm just not sure how to go about calculating the complexity of the whole algorithm

Comment: So it takes n^2 to insert into the list and then nlg(n) to sort and you're going to do this n-1 times(right?) So: I would say it's (n-1)*( n^2 + n*lg(n) ) =~ n^3 + n^2 * lg(n), so big O(n^3)?

Comment: Your question implies that the array is size n-1 and all linked lists are size n. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

"each linked list is first insertion sorted"

This makes for a complexity of `O(n) * O(m^2)`, or `O(n*m^2)` - we have to use a different letter because the length of each list is not related to the number of lists.

"then the array is quicksorted"

That adds `O(n log n)`.

Total: `O(n*m^2 + n log n)`, which simpifies to `O(n*m^2)` (the `n log n` is not significant compared to the `n*m^2`).

Comment: I'm not an expert on big-O notation, so don't be too hard on my if I'm wrong :p

Comment: Technically speaking, you should have O(max(nm^2, nlogn)). Then again, Quicksort is O(n^2) in the worst case, so unless this is an average-case analysis, it would be more technically correct to answer O(max(nm^2, n^2)). Just saying. You want a worst-case O(nlogn) algorithm, try merge or heap sort.